# Lock Excel 2013 cells based on other cell input

Tags: vba, excel

I have a worksheet with many different columns for input. The columns in question are D, H, and I. D and H are drop downs. I is any text input. I am trying to put together a VBA script so that if a selection is made in D2 then that will lock H2 and I2. If a selection is made in H2 then that will lock D2 and I2. If text is entered in I2 then that will lock D2 and H2. Lastly, this will need to be done for the entire column of D, H, and I so that each cell in those columns have the same property i.e. D16 and H16 will lock if I16 is filled and so on and so forth.

If this can be implemented by formulas as well I do not mind.

```
  `  Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Cells)
            If ActiveSheet.Cells(2, 4).Text = True Then 
'This is what I don't understand. I don't know what to set the text to. I'm trying to say if there's anything in the cell Then do the following...
                ActiveSheet.Cells(2, 8).Locked = True
                ActiveSheet.Cells(2, 9).Locked = True
            Else
                ActiveSheet.Cells(2, 8).Text = True Then
                ActiveSheet.Cells(2, 4).Locked = True
                ActiveSheet.Cells(2, 9).Locked = True
            Else
                ActiveSheet.Cells(2, 9).Text = True Then
                ActiveSheet.Cells(2, 4).Locked = True
                ActiveSheet.Cells(2, 8).Locked = True
            End If
    End Sub`
```

Comment: So have you tried anything?

Comment: I don't understand the drop down. If it's in D2, how will H3 ever be affected given that user would never select D3?

Comment: @ScottCraner, I was working off of this but can't figure how to work it out for my situation: http://database.ittoolbox.com/groups/technical-functional/excel-l/how-to-lockunlock-an-excel-cell-based-on-the-contents-of-another-cell-4625040

Comment: @findwindow There are drop downs for the entirety of cells in column D. So only D3 should affect H3 or I3.

Comment: So what is not working in the code you are trying.  Please post in your original post with the edit selection, what you have.  And tell us what is not working.

Comment: @ScottCraner So I don't know what to set the text to. Can I just set it to True? So that if anything is inputted in the cell it does so and so  statements? The second piece would be how do I implement that code for every cell in the columns?

Comment: You want to determine the row of target and then lock that row in the other columns.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this code, but bear in mind locking cells as **no affect** unless the worksheet is protected. Also note that `ByVal Target as Range` is the correct syntax for the `Worksheet_Change` argument (not `ByVal Target as Cells`).

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

If Len(Target) Then

    Select Case Target.Column

        Case Is = 4

            Me.Unprotect "pwd"
            Cells(Target.Row, 8).Locked = True
            Cells(Target.Row, 9).Locked = True
            Me.Protect "pwd"

        Case Is = 8

            Me.Unprotect "pwd"
            Cells(Target.Row, 4).Locked = True
            Cells(Target.Row, 9).Locked = True
            Me.Protect "pwd"

        Case Is = 9

            Me.Unprotect "pwd"
            Cells(Target.Row, 4).Locked = True
            Cells(Target.Row, 8).Locked = True
            Me.Protect "pwd"

    End Select

End If

End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks! However, this seems to be giving me a runtime error. Run-time error '1004': Unable to set the Locked property of the Range class. Also, still able to edit the fields which is probably due to the error. The logic you have makes sense reading it, but I don't know how to debug the error it's giving.

Comment: I placed code to unlock the worksheet and then lock it around each change, since you most likely have your worksheet protected.

Comment: Oh, okay. Let me try that.

Comment: obviously change `pwd` to whatever your password is :)

Comment: haha thanks! Is there a way to make this iterate through every cell? Or will it all have be programmed manually for each scenario? I'm asking because I'll want to do this for at leas D2-D100 if not the entire sheet.

Comment: right now, anytime a cell is changed it will check to see if that cell is column D, H or I and then lock the corresponding row of the edited cell in column D, H and / or I, respectively. Is that what you need? Or do you want to lock rows 2-100 everytime a change is made in D, H or I?

Comment: sorry you're correct. It's already for the entire sheet. Thank you for your help!